Scalping for tradingview indicators results using python

How can you you scalp tradingview indicator results using python from tradingview as show from the above screenshoot
What I want to achieve

Login into my Tradingview account
Scalp Tradingview indicator results using python
Get  BUY or SELL signal from the Trading view indicator

The solution which looks to be promising is to use Selenium to read the web page DOM but the problem is that Chart and indicator are on the canvas
Below is the code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
browser.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/")
timeout = 10
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()
MAMA_element=browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/span[3]/span')
print(MAMA_element.text)

I expect to acheive the following

Login into my Tradingview account
Scalp Tradingview indicator results using python
Get  BUY or SELL signal from the Trading view indicator


'Scalp'. I don't think it means what you think it means.

Scalping is a trading style that specializes in profiting off small price changes and making a fast profit off reselling

Exactly, so do you need help with your trading, or some other kind of help?

I need help and steps which I can take to develop a python bot
